# Why python does not return reference?

Tags: python

I have a question about how Python return value.
Below is my simple python code practicing recursive function.

```py
def brackets(ans, n, cur, open, close):
    if len(cur) == n*2:
        ans.append(cur)   # <---l.1
        return ans        # <---l.2   

    if open < n:
        brackets(ans, n,cur+"(",open+1,close)

    if open > close:
        brackets(ans, n,cur+")",open,close+1)

ans = []
ret = brackets(ans, 2, "", 0,0)  # <---l.3
print(ans)
print(ret)

===== 
return:
['(())', '()()']
None
```

I think I modify `ans` list object on the line l.1 and return it, and on line l.2, I pass the `ans` reference on line l.3. 
But when I print both value `ans` and `ret`, `ret` does not contain same value as `ans`.

Of course, I just print `ans` out for correct answer but I expected Python initialized variable `ret` and assigned `brackets` return reference to `ret` on line l.3.

I got confused how python pass the reference through a function. Please let me know the relevant documents or the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of `cur` is not `n*2`, the `brackets()` function does not return any value. It isn't easy to know what it should return, to be honest, because you have not posted some expected results. That said, here are some options:

1. Always return the value of the recursive call:

   ```
    if open < n:
        return brackets(ans, n,cur+"(",open+1,close)

    if open > close:
        return brackets(ans, n,cur+")",open,close+1)
   ```

   In this case, this will be the end result:

   ```
    ['(())']
    ['(())']
   ```

   or
2. Return `ans` at the end of the function:

   ```
    return ans
   ```

   This will be the output:

   ```
    ['(())', '()()']
    ['(())', '()()']
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of *variable scope*. The variable inside the function `brackets` is different than the one outside the function, even if they have the same name (`ans`). [Here is an article](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-variable-scope/) that might help you with this.